# How to bring file in physical location to model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a model as below

```
public class request_dtls
{
    [Key]
    public long request_detail_id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name  { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("request_dtls")]
    public virtual IList<dtls_doc> dtls_doc { get; set; }
}

public class dtls_doc
{
    [Key]
    public long doc_line_id { get; set; }
    public long request_detail_id { get; set; }
    public string file_name { get; set; }
    public string document_name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UpFile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("request_detail_id"), InverseProperty("dtls_doc")]
    public virtual request_dtls request_dtls { get; set; }
}
```

And in view multiple documents will add to each details and its saving successfully. The file path will save in detail level and dtl_doc table contain document names etc.

Now I need to retrieve the uploaded file and show in another view.

I wrote the view as below

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    if (Model.dtls_doc != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.dtls_doc.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model > Model.dtls_doc[i].request_detail_id);
            @Html.HiddenFor(model > Model.dtls_doc[i].doc_line_id);
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtls_doc[i].document_name)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtls_doc[i].UpFile, new { type = "file" })
            <input type="hidden" name="dtls_doc.Index" value="@i" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and it give below screen

[image]

how can i bring the physically stored files corresponding to each "chooseFile" button like below

[image]

**Edited**

```
 <table id="doc" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

 <tr>
 <th style="width:200px">
  Document Name
</th>

 <th style="width:500px">
  File to Upload
  </th>
<th style="width:6px">
</th>
</tr>
@if (Model != null)
    {
        if (Model.dtls_doc != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.dtls_doc.Count; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model > Model.dtls_doc[i].request_detail_id);
                @Html.HiddenFor(model > Model.dtls_doc[i].doc_line_id);
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtls_doc[i].document_name)</td>
            <td>
@Html.ActionLink("Download File", "download_file", new { id = Model.dtl_doc_dtls[i].doc_line_id })
                <input type="hidden" name="dtls_doc.Index" value="@i" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

this give the below result...for existing it will be a link to download and it is downloading.
For new it will be a File type

[image]

**template for new added row**

```
  <table id="Newdoc" style="display:none">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text"  name="dtls_doc[#].document_name" value /></td>

<td>
<input type="file"  name="dtls_doc[#].UpFile" />

<input type="hidden" name="dtls_doc.Index" value="%" />
 </td>
<td><input id="doc_delete" class="doc_delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery for adding new row**

```
 $("#N").click(function (event) {

                event.preventDefault();
                var index = (new Date()).getTime();
                var clone = $('#Newdoc').clone();
                clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
                clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
                var html = clone.html();
                $("#doc").append(clone.html());


            });
```

**Jquery for removing a row**

```
 $('#doc').on('click', 'td input.doc_delete', function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });
```

But when submitting the form the newly added files are not getting at controller..it show 3 count
[image]

Comment: Not clear what you asking here. In the 2nd view you need either an `<img>` tag to display the file, or a llink to download the file. And its not clear why you 2nd view has hidden inputs of all you wanting to do is display the information.

Comment: @StephenMuecke from second view he can download or delete and upload new files also..so using that hiddenfield i can update the exiting record..

Comment: OK, Your going about this the wrong way. I'm about to upload a project to GitHub that includes methods to do all this, but it wont be for a day or 2 (and you cannot set the value of a file input for security reasons - the only way it can be set is by the user selecting a file in the browser)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Im happy to wait for 2 more days :D

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok understand for an existing file we can only show them to download..if they want they can delete that record and insert new

Comment: Yes, For existing `dtls_doc` items, you just display the file name that you have saved (along with a delete button etc). You only create a file input for adding new files. I'll ping you when I have uploaded the project (it does all you want and more in just one line of code in your view and a couple in the controller)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok i will wait ..thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137038/discussion-between-sachu-and-stephen-muecke).